# problem starting activity in android

Tags: android

I have an issue starting a new activity. I would like to start an activity so that the user can pick a list of contacts his/her contact list.
This is what i have to start an intent, its triggered by a button click.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, kPickContact);
```

I get this error

```
09-14 01:34:04.402: ERROR/ActivityManager(106): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup, calling user: android.uid.system:1000, calling package is one of: [com.google.android.backup, com.android.providers.settings, com.android.systemui, com.android.providers.subscribedfeeds, com.android.settings, android, com.android.server.vpn]
09-14 01:34:04.402: ERROR/ActivityManager(106):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:144)
09-14 01:34:04.402: ERROR/ActivityManager(106):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
09-14 01:34:04.402: ERROR/ActivityManager(106):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.getType(ContentProviderNative.java:387)
09-14 01:34:04.402: ERROR/ActivityManager(106):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getProviderMimeType(ActivityManagerService.java:5586)
09-14 01:34:04.402: ERROR/ActivityManager(106):     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:1267)
09-14 01:34:04.402: ERROR/ActivityManager(106):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1467)
```

I hate dumping error logs here, but i am so new to android i have no idea how to parse this crash log. Can someone a) give me insight into what i am doing wrong and b) point me to some resources as to how to read these crash logs?

Comment: Here is a link for contacts API : http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html

Comment: @Android-Droid link doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list of the contacts to use this query.

```
  Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { Phone._ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER },
            null, null, null);

    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    cursor.getColumnCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
        contactName.add(cursor.getString(1));

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be too late but hope to be of help to someone...

Instead of 
`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI);` 
you should use 
`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);`

Though from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI) it is advised to use `Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI`